# Why we have 2 folders for web templates in folder (12 hive > Template)

Tags: 2007, site-template

I have two folders in 12 Hive > Template named as  "1033" and "Site template".

In folder "1033" I can see having different "STS....." and then these folders got some custom template folders contains sub folders named as "DOCTemp" and then DOCTEMP folder contains more folders like  DCL, FP, XMLFORMS...

however in Site Template folder I got templates folder STS with xml folder and ONET.xml files in them.

Can someone explain "1033" folder and then DOCTEMP in it's concept please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know 1033 is the english language set. In comparison Japanese is 1041.

Anything inside 1033 applies to the 1033 language pack and can be different from other files in other language packs. DOCTEMP contains all the document templates in a site for Word(../WORD), Excel(../XL), InfoPath(../XMLFORMS), PowerPoint(../PPT), Web Part Pages(../SMARTPGS), etc.